# Specifying classpath on execution

Tags: java, class, jar

I'm trying to specify the classpath of my package when i run my program, like this:

`java –cp .;my.package.jar MyMainClass`

my.package.jar lies in the same directory as MyMainClass.class.

I'm getting this error message:

`Could not find or load main class ?cp`

It seems like it is not recognizing the switch `-cp`, and is instead trying to find a class named `cp`. Anyone know what may cause this?

Comment: how is your jar file called exactly? Surely not my.package.jar

Comment: Adding OS and JDK details with question, would have saved efforts?

Comment: That `?` you get in the error message looks suspicious. Are you some way copy-pasting the command and the `-` isn't really a regular `-`? Try typing the command into the terminal manually

Comment: My bad, JDK 8 Update 45, Windows 7. @CodeRunner it's java1.media.jar actually, I know this is an odd naming, but it's a school assignment and we were tasked to name it this.

Comment: @KErlandsson Wow...that was it... i'll just go hide in a corner somewhere, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on *nix, the class path separator is `:`, not `;`. In that case you need to run `java –cp .:my.package.jar MyMainClass`.

Otherwise if you are on widows, that `?` you get in the error message looks suspicious. Are you some way copy-pasting the command and the `-` isn't really a regular `-`? Try typing the command into the terminal manually.

Comment: Great, will add that to the answer

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using old version of Java which recognizes only full name - use
`-classpath` instead of `-cp`

Comment: I'm on JDK 8 Update 45, just reinstalled it and still have the issue.